# When is it good and bad to use a string parameter in a function?

Tags: java, coding-style

I saw a pull request come in the other day that had a string as a parameter in a function where the string wasn't modified. Instead, the string was used to toggle between what the function does.

What are the pros and cons of doing it this way vs creating separate functions like `getNewTableVersion` / `getOldTableVersion` to omit the `tableType` parameter?

```
public static String getTableVersion(String prefix, String tableVersion, String tableType) {
    String[] tableVersions = tableVersion.split(prefix);
    Integer version;
    switch (tableType) {
      case "new":
        // set version to newer one
      case "old":
        // set version to older one
      default:
        // default functionality
    }

    return prefix + version.toString();
}
```

For the record, I believe this is a bad practice. I think with a list of pros and cons I may be able to convince the developer not to do this.

Comment: I don't think there'd be any pros to this besides making bad code easy to write in the short term.

Comment: Questions about coding style best practices are generally more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: @Barmar I saw the `coding-style` tag and thought it was the correct community. Is it possible to move the question?

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer Flag it and ask the moderators.

Comment: I believe this is more objective than opinion based. I'm asking for when is it an appropriate time to use a string parameter as a functional toggle, if not, what are the reasons why. Any constructive criticism would help so I can improve the wording of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it is bad practice, because you cannot infer the functionality of the function from its prototype. It reeks of magical constants.

If you want to do something like this, an option is to use an `enum` to limit the possibilities of the `tableType` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I believe bringing up magic constants would definitely bolster my argument. I haven't accepted this as an answer as I'd like to hear from others when this question is moved to the correct community.

Comment: Note that the enum can also contain the functionality or information from the switch statement--so  tableTypeEnum.version could return the version number directly.

Comment: @BillK obviously, but I reckon the code does a little more than that, perhaps getting some info from a database.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Perhaps, just thought I'd mention it. Besides, I actually use enums that retrieve information from the database...  Makes for a great set of database-based "constants".